# Is it possible to use a raspberry pi to control these LED strips?

Tags: led, raspberry-pi, led-strip

I want to control some LED strips (inside PVC tubes) with a raspberry pi. Is this possible? Where would I start?

The problems are, I don't have a lot of info about the strips:

- LED Chip Model:SMD5050
- Brand:Epistar
- LED Chip:Epistar 48PCS SMD
- Input voltage:DC12V DMX512 led digital tube
- Power:Around 12W/Tube DMX512 tube

[image]
I got about 80 of these tubes. The idea is to build a 40 by 2 tube array and to use it as a display.

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: Maybe, a commom digital-controllable LED chip is [WS2812](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/WS2812.pdf). However, others might be compatible with it.

Comment: DMX512, what you mentioned is a [standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMX512) for digital communication networks.

Comment: Most things are controllable via a Pi.

Comment: DMX is a kind of async serial protocol and the Pi's  UART might should be able to manage that.

the 11 bit symbol frame size could be a problem however.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Keep in mind that *"Is it possible ...?"* is a yes/no question. In this case, the answer is "Yes". If you're asking us to design it for you, that would be too broad. You would need to specify something about the level of performance you expect as well as what constraints you have on the implementation. What is your specific question?

Answer (score 4):

For DMX512 you need a UART capable of 250000 baud and 8 data bits with two stop bits (or 8 data bits a space for parity and one stop bit)

I tried a cheap* RS485 dongle and while it claimed to manage the necessary framing minicom couldn't make it do 250000 baud.

I'm not sure what the exact capabilities if the Raspberry Pi main UART are.

(*)it cost less than $1

it looks like FTDI uarts can do 250000 Baud so one of them and an RS485 interface chip should probably get you there.

You can of course buy DMX adaptors that connect to USB or to GPIO but shopping questions are off topic here.

Comment: Given that you're unable to say if the pi's UART can accomplish the task, this is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: yeah, but too long and detailed to fit into comments,